# Custom msbuild task configuration problem

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have a custom `MSBuild` task, which must have some configuration values. I would like to place those values into my application config file, but that doesn't work. I can of course place those values into csproj directly, but that would require a user to unload/edit/reload csproj in order to do a simple configuration change.

I'm also thinking of adding custom nuget commands to automate this, but not sure, if it is a good decision.

To summarize: my `MSBuild` task needs to be easily configured, ideally via the `Web.config`. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `web.config` or `app.config` are unappropriated for storing MSBuild parameters. This is completely different things - application configuration and application build process details.

You can create your custom `Build.properties` file which contains single `<PropertyGroup>` node with a set of properties (property per each configuration parameter), then just import this properties file in your build targets or directly in csproj file like

```
<Import Project="Build.properties" />
```